# Multi criterion search across time

Tags: mongodb, search, solr

I'm looking for a elegant and scalable way of searching through meta informations of some entities across time.

Let's take the following meta changing over time for entity A and B

```
[{
    "idEntity": "A",
    "name": "Name of A",
    "rating": 0.5,
    "description": "Some short description of A",
    "createdAtWeek": 1
}, {
    "idEntity": "B",
    "name": "Name of B",
    "rating": 0.2,
    "description": "Some short description of B",
    "createdAtWeek": 1
}, {
    "idEntity": "A",
    "name": "Name of A improved",
    "rating": 0.5,
    "description": "Some longer description of A",
    "createdAtWeek": 2
}, {
    "idEntity": "A",
    "name": "Name of A improved",
    "rating": 0.6,
    "description": "Some longer description of A",
    "createdAtWeek": 3
}]
```

I want to be able to find entities (unique) for which the last meta matches `rating >= 0.2` and that contain the word `of` in their `description`. I also want to be able to go in the past a look for these same criterion but that would need to give me different result.

The most easy way to do this through Mongo would be to make an aggregation pipeline but that's too slow if the collection is getting big.

Hence I went and duplicated all the documents so that each week (1-3) gets it's full data which allows me to include the `createdAtWeek` in the query straightly and be sure I have consistent results across time.

But you can see where this leads, huge duplication making the collection enormous for nothing.

Hence I tried to look at storing these documents in Solr, but when looking at the documentation there doesn't seem to be a way to first group the results by entity and date and then search within the grouping.

Is there another way to achieve the same results as the duplication without actually duplicating?

Comment: Rather than write a novel for a question, it would be better if you could show by example in **"one"** chosen technology what you actually want to achieve. Tagging to the interest of "two competing" technolgies and simply asking the "does Coke or Pepsi taste better?" question is not really useful to anyone. Way too broad and opinion based a question for here.

Comment: I thought that abstracting the question would make lot of sense in this case rather than obtaining an answer that would be too focus on one technology. But I'm going to rephrase it as you seem to have some experience here.

Answer (score 0):

Solr Block Join Query Parser can handle this kind of operations.

The data structure is changed toward a hierarchical system and the `createdAtWeek` is replaced with `validSince_i` and `validUntil_i`.

```
/* Entity A */
{
  "path_s": "1.entity",
  "id": "A",
  "_childDocuments_": [
    {
      "path_s": "2.metadata.rating",
      "id": "2.metadata.rating.1",
      "_childDocuments_": [
        {
          "path_s": "3.metadata.rating.timeValidity",
          "id": "2.metadata.rating.timeValidity.1",
          "validSince_i": -1,
          "validUntil_i": 2,
          "value_f": 0.5
        },
        {
          "path_s": "3.metadata.rating.timeValidity",
          "id": "2.metadata.rating.timeValidity.2",
          "validSince_i": 3,
          "validUntil_i": 9999999,
          "value_f": 0.6
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path_s": "2.metadata.description",
      "id": "2.metadata.description.1",
      "_childDocuments_": [
        {
          "path_s": "3.metadata.description.timeValidity",
          "id": "2.metadata.description.timeValidity.1",
          "validSince_i": -1,
          "validUntil_i": 1,
          "value_txt_en": "Some short description of A"
        },
        {
          "path_s": "3.metadata.description.timeValidity",
          "id": "2.metadata.description.timeValidity.2",
          "validSince_i": 2,
          "validUntil_i": 9999999,
          "value_txt_en": "Some longer description of A"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
/* Entity B */
{
  "path_s": "1.entity",
  "id": "B",
  "_childDocuments_": [
    {
      "path_s": "2.metadata.rating",
      "id": "2.metadata.rating.2",
      "_childDocuments_": [
        {
          "path_s": "3.metadata.rating.timeValidity",
          "id": "2.metadata.rating.timeValidity.3",
          "validSince_i": -1,
          "validUntil_i": 9999999,
          "value_f": 0.2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

BlockJoin can now be leveraged with faceting as long as the timeValidities are not overlapping each other like so:

```
fq={!parent which="path_s:1.entity"}(path_s:3.metadata.rating.timeValidity AND validUntil_i:[2 TO *] AND value_f:[0.3 TO *])&fq={!parent which="path_s:1.entity"}(path_s:3.metadata.description.timeValidity AND validUntil_i:[2 TO *] AND value_txt_en:short)&q=*:*
```

Which returns no entities as there are no entities later than week 2 that have a `rating >= 0.3` with a description containing `short`

Running the following works fine too

```
fq={!parent which="path_s:1.entity"}(path_s:3.metadata.rating.timeValidity AND validUntil_i:[2 TO *] AND value_f:[0.3 TO *])&fq={!parent which="path_s:1.entity"}(path_s:3.metadata.description.timeValidity AND validUntil_i:[2 TO *] AND value_txt_en:longer)&q=*:*
```

As you can see entity A shows up as its rating is >= 0.3 after week >= 2 with the description containing `longer`.

Performance aspect needs to be asserted but it does the job and avoids duplicates.